# Banach Fractal Curve Java - Recursive

Tags: java, recursion, curve, fractals

I have the following Banach Fractal problem:
The so-called Banach Curve can be generated using the following fractal rule:

1. Draw a circle.
2. Draw 9 smaller circles, each with a radius ⅓ of the original
   circle. One of the smaller circles should have the same center as that of the original circle. The centers of the remaining
   8 smaller circles should be equally spaced along the circumference of the original circle.
3. Repeat step b with each of the smaller circles.

Note: The circle of radius r centered at point (x, y) is the set of all the points
(x + r · cos(t), y + r · sin(t)) where 0 ≤ t ≤ 2π , and t is given in radians. I can use `Math.toRadians()` 
Guidelines:

- Only recursive solutions, no loops allowed
- No imports & no lists (so no map or so) & no `?`
- I can only use the functions `public static void banachCurve(int n)` and help functions  `private static void banachCurve(double x, double y, double r, int n)`

  - Can only use StdDraw to draw or call other functions from it, no other Std classes are allowed

I thought of adding circles each time since there are supposed to be 9 at the edges and 1 in the center each time, however I can only seem to get the circles on the right or left, and for some reason a RuntimeError.

```
public static void banachCurve(int n) {

        banachCurve (0.5,0.5,1,n);
    }

    private static void banachCurve(double x, double y, double r, int n) {
       if (n == 0) {
           return;
       }
       double d = (r/3);
       StdDraw.circle (x,y,d);
//       StdDraw.ellipse(x, y, r, r);
       banachCurve (x + d, y, d, n - 1); // centre
       banachCurve (x + d+ d, y+d, d, n--); // left
       banachCurve (x , y + d, d, n--); // right
       banachCurve (x+d , y +d+ d, d, n--);
        banachCurve (x+d , y +d, d, n--);

    }
```

my output: 
[image: my output]
stages of Banach Curve:
[image: Stages of Banach Curve]

Comment: On a purely aesthetic note, if you used 6 smaller versions instead of 8, you could avoid any overlaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `n--`, you are passing `n` to the function and then decrementing it by one for the next call. Instead, you need to pass `n - 1` to each call, as the call itself will decrement `n` further in its own recursive call, eventually stopping at `0` as you correctly have.

For the four cardinal points, using `(x + d, y)`, `(x, y + d)`, `(x - d, y)` and `(x, y - d)` works correctly, but for the four diagonal points, you will need to use either the square root (`Math.sqrt`) for the Pythagoras method, or the sine and cosine (`Math.sin` and `Math.cos`) for the trigonometric method. Using `(x + d, y + d)` and the like would place them on a square instead.

Assuming that `x` and `y` mark the centre of your circle, your function will then become:

```
private static void banachCurve(final double x, final double y, final double r, final int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }
    final double d = r / 3;
    StdDraw.circle (x, y, d);
    banachCurve (x, y, d, n - 1);     // centre
    banachCurve (x, y + d, d, n - 1); // north
    banachCurve (x + d, y, d, n - 1); // east
    banachCurve (x, y - d, d, n - 1); // south
    banachCurve (x - d, y, d, n - 1); // west
    // Get the diagonal radius for a point at 45 degrees on the circle
    final double diagD = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(45)) * d;
    banachCurve (x + diagD, y + diagD, d, n - 1); // north-east
    banachCurve (x + diagD, y - diagD, d, n - 1); // south-east
    banachCurve (x - diagD, y - diagD, d, n - 1); // south-west
    banachCurve (x - diagD, y + diagD, d, n - 1); // north-west
}
```

Here is the output for `banachCurve(0.5, 0.5, 1, 6);`:

[image: Banach Curve for recursion depth of 6.]

Comment: Thank you, however for n = 6 (which is the picture) the output is 5 circles each time and it focuses only on the center circle instead of stage 2

Comment: @Yuki1112 I have just tested my own code (I fixed the `diagD` calculation in the answer) and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to drag `Math.cos()` into the picture, a la the currenly accepted answer, why not go the whole hog and use sine and cosine to move around the circle:

```
private static void banachCurve(double x, double y, double r, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }

    double d = r / 3;
    StdDraw.circle (x, y, d);

    banachCurve (x, y, d, n - 1); // center

    for (double angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 45) {
        double theta = Math.toRadians(angle);
        double dx = x + d * Math.cos(theta);
        double dy = y + d * Math.sin(theta);

        banachCurve (dx, dy, d, n - 1);
    }
}
```

Output for `banachCurve(0.5, 0.5, 1, 3);`

[image]

This approach makes easy work of testing out @tucuxi's suggestion, of six instead of eight surrounding circles.  Just increase the increment angle in the `for` loop from 45 to 60:

[image]

Though I can't say its an improvement over the original design.  Though seven surrounding circles, again trivial to test given this code design, catches one's eye:

[image]